# Adding date to Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add to my ActionBar date. I use this code :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date());
actionBar.setTitle(dateString);
```

When I save my Activity I get an error which tells me to add String or getSupportActionBar(); method. I do not need either of this how canI get threw this error.?

I get:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String

2 quick fixes available:

1)Add cast to 'String'
2)Change type of 'dateString' to 'CharSequance'

Comment: could you post the error/exception you've got ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format()` method returns a `CharSequence`. This *may* be a `String`, or it could be something else.

You can call `toString()` on a `CharSequence` to ensure that you coerce it to be a `String`. So, try:

```
String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date()).toString();
```